# Black Screen afet ram upgrade on acer aspire one

Tags: memory, upgrade, acer-aspire

So I tried upgrading my acer aspire one 725's ram from 2GB to 4GB by replacing the 2GB Ram module with a new 4GB ram module.

The result is that i get a black screen when starting the computer. 
If change back to the 2GB it runs fine.
When I start the laptop with no ram it starts beeping. Shouldn't it beep too if it can't recongize the 4GB Ram Module because it is defect or not supported?

I am using DDR3 SODIMM ram.

Do I need to reset or upgrade my bios? How do I do that?

Update:

Information about RAM:

4GB Module - DDR3L 1600MHz

Part Number: KVR16LSE11/4

Specs: DDR3L, 1600MHz, ECC, CL11, 1R, X8, 1.35V, Unbuffered, SODIMM,

(http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/?partid=kvr16lse11/4)

Update:

This is the memory recommended by crucial.com for my netbook:

4GB DDR3 PC3-12800 Unbuffered NON-ECC 1.35V
CT5663538

```
Brand: Crucial
Form Factor: SODIMM
Module Size: 4GB
Warranty: Limited Lifetime
Specs: DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR3-1600 • 1.35V •
Series: Crucial
```

(http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/aspire-one-725/CT5663538)

So as crucial recommends non-ecc ram it looks like my motherboard doesn't support ecc and it is not compatible.

Comment: Which question are you asking, should it beep or do you need to reset your BIOS? What have you researched on Acer's support site?

Comment: We need more information on the memory you had and the memory you purchased.  `DDR3 SODIMM` isn't enough information.

Comment: Adding to Ramhound's comment, you might want to run the memory profiler on www.crucial.com and see if the RAM you bought matches the settings and speeds it suggests you need.

Comment: I only see information for one of the two modules your asking about.  We need information about the original modules that do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motherboard is clearly functional since it starts with the old memory stick. That means the new memory is either unsupported or defective.

My guess would be that the motherboard does not support ECC ram, but it could also be the memory size or speed.